# Required tag and invalid form submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, required

I have this page with form and it has required tags on few inputs. When I leave them empty and try to submit my form through Ajax it obviously says " This field is required " and now when I type them in and try to submit my form it still says that " This field is required ", has anyone had similar bug before? I really don't know where to look.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Post your full code. So that can find where is the issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m07ZQ6X7

Comment: Okay, the error dissapeared when I removed oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('See väli on nõutav')" from the input which was required, but how can I add custom error then

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('See väli on nõutav')" tag on the required input. Problem was removed after removing this field.